# batch script to zip IIS Log files(text files) and copy to another folder with daily scheduling

Tags: windows, iis, batch-file

The task is to Zip IIS Log Files(text files) and copy to another folder based on yesterday's date. And this batch script has to be Scheduled everyday.

I am very new to batch scripting. Any help is appreciated..!! Thanks.

I have this code which is copying the latest 3 files. But, I want to copy files only created on yesterday's date. And my file naming format is a_bc130510(a_bcYYMMDD).

```
enter code here

@ECHO OFF
SET srcdir=D:\IIS LOGS
SET tgtdir=D:\FileCopy
SET /A topcnt=3
SET /A cnt=0
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%F IN ('DIR /A-D /OD /TW /B "%srcdir%"') DO (
SET /A cnt+=1
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
IF !cnt! GTR !topcnt! (ENDLOCAL & GOTO :EOF)
ENDLOCAL
COPY "%srcdir%\%%F" "%tgtdir%"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is modified to copy the newest file from yesterday, as you asked.

This assumes your log filenames are `abcYYMMDD.log`
Change the term `"%srcdir%\*%day%.log"` if you need something else.

```
@echo off
call :getdate today -1
SET "srcdir=D:\IIS LOGS"
SET "tgtdir=D:\FileCopy"
FOR /F "delims=" %%F IN ('DIR /A-D /O-D /TW /B "%srcdir%\*%day%.log"') DO (
COPY "%srcdir%\%%F" "%tgtdir%"
goto :done
)
:done
rem extra code after the copy goes here
goto :EOF
:getdate
set date1=%1
set qty=%2
set separator=%~3
if /i "%date1%" EQU "TODAY" (set date1=now) else (set date1="%date1%")
echo >"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" s=DateAdd("d",%qty%,%date1%)
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" WScript.Echo year(s)^&_
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs"         right(100+month(s),2)^&_
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs"         right(100+day(s),2)
for /f %%a in ('cscript //nologo "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"') do set result=%%a
del "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"
endlocal& set "YY=%result:~2,4%"&set "MM=%result:~4,2%"&set "DD=%result:~6,2%"
set "day=%YY%%separator%%MM%%separator%%DD%"
goto :EOF
```

Comment: Thanks for ur help. I actually want to copy only file which is generated for the previous day. Whereas here, it is copying top 3 files present. 
Also, how to copy multiple files on the same date. 
And, I also need to Zip the file and then copy to the target folder. 
Thanks again..!! :)

Comment: See the edit I have made above.  Put any extra code where indicated.  Extra questions should be asked in another thread.